# Using .split() method and getting only part of the string array created back

Tags: java

I need to read the text from a .dat file that goes as such:

```
4
Mary 13.99
Ruth 22.04
Anne 12.39
Talor 18.34
```

I used a buffered reader that looks like this:

```
public class Tester{

    public static void main(String [] args){

       BufferedReader reader = null;

       try {
           File file = new File("C:\\Users\\hoguetm\\workspace\\practiceproblems\\beautiful.dat");
           reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

           String line;

           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               //System.out.println(line);
               //split will go here
               String[] str1Array =  line.split(" ");
               System.out.println(str1Array[0]);

               //works

               /*
               for (String retval: line.split(" ")){
                    System.out.println(retval);
               }
               */
           }

       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           try {
               reader.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
```

}

i need to add the numbers at the end of the lines except the 4 and print the sum out, but when i change [0] to [1] it says out of range. please help

Comment: It is saying it is out of range because the first line you see only has the string "4" in it.

Comment: Try printing out the line you read, and the full array you parsed from it. Check your data coming in is as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input file is *guaranteed* to be in the format you posted, you can simply do this:

```
reader.readLine();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    ...
```

This would cause your reader to consume the first line of the file and ignore it completely. That said, the file you've posted *suggests* that the first line indicates the number of lines which follow, implying that you *should* parse it and use a `for` loop. For example:

```
int nLines = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
for(int i = 0; i < nLines; i++)
{
    line = reader.readLine();
    ...
}
```

That's based entirely on the small sample you've provided, though. More information on the dat file's specification would be useful.

Comment: Yes the format is guaranteed.  How would I add all the values at [1] of the array?

Comment: @user3070681, Your code is largely fine, you just weren't accounting for the first line of the file. `Double.parseDouble(str1Array[1])` should get you the value on the given line.

Comment: how would i go about summing all of the values?

Comment: how would i sum all the values?

Comment: @user3070681, Outside of your loop, declare a variable of type `double`, initialized to 0. Inside of the loop, add the parsed value of `strArray[1]` to your variable.

Answer (score 3):

Don't split the first line. Do split  second line onward.

```
reader.readLine(); //added this line

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the first line only has one field.  Try this instead:

```
double total = 0;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           String[] str1Array =  line.split(" ");
           if(str1Array.length > 1) {
               System.out.println(str1Array[1]);
               total += Double.parseDouble(str1Array[1]);
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `String.split(String)` method discards all emtpy Strings at the end of the array as per API-Documentation. If you ned to get back fixed-size arrays use `line.split(" ",-1)` - but be prepared to handle empty Strings in the result.

Answer (score 0):

1 is out of range for that first row.  `String.split()` will return an array with 1 element (the entire line) for that first line, and then an array with 2 elements for all other lines.

What's the general format of this .dat file?  Is it always a single number on the first line, then name/number pairs for all subsequent lines?  If that's the case, I would suggest ignoring the first line (with an extra `reader.readLine()` call before the loop.  Or can the single-number lines be peppered throughout the file?  If that's the case, then I would suggest checking the length of the array each time through the loop, and only doing the add if the length is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int count =Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
String line;
while (count>0) {
    line = reader.readLine();             

    //System.out.println(line);
  //split will go here

 String[] str1Array =  line.split(" ");
System.out.println(str1Array[0]);

   //works

           /*
           for (String retval: line.split(" ")){
                System.out.println(retval);
           }
           */
 count--;
       }
```